# ioredis - Ignore request if redis is down

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I'm using ioredis.
In order to prevent a huge buffer that can crash my app, I want to ignore requests when redis is down, and to catch those requests.
Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

For other people finding this who want a bit more help. This intercepts commends to ioredis and just returns false if it's not in a ready state.

```
// Proxify commands to redis client.
// If redis is unavailable then return false.
// This stops everything dying if redis is down.
module.exports.redis = new Proxy(client, {
  get(target, property, receiver) {
    if (client.status !== 'ready') {
      return (() => false);
    }
    return Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [circuit breaker design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern).

> Circuit breaker is a design pattern used in modern software development. It is used to detect failures and encapsulates the logic of preventing a failure from constantly recurring, during maintenance, temporary external system failure or unexpected system difficulties.
>
> Generally Circuit Breaker can be used to check the availability of an external service. An external service can be a database server or a web service used by the application.

Martin fowler's [blog post](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html) has a good explanation and a basic implementation about how to do it.